# Como saber cada pixel de um superpixel em MatLab?

Tags: imagem, matlab, processamento-de-imagens

estou fazendo um programa em MatLab usando o addon de visão computacional. Usei a função superpixels para obter a matriz de labels. Pelo que entendi essa matriz representa a qual label (superpixel) cada pixel da imagem pertence. Porém, tem algo que eu não estou entendendo.

Essa matriz de label deveria ser do mesmo tamanho da imagem original entretanto quando checo os valores de linha e coluna de cada uma, aparece um valor de coluna diferente.

Eu estou fazendo isso:

```
I = imread('barco3.jpg');
figure
imshow(I)
[l,c] = size(I);
[L,N] = superpixels(I,500);
[m,n] = size(L);
```

E quando vejo os valores de l,c,m,n aparece valores diferentes entre c e n (colunas da imagem original e da matriz de label L)

```
l = 331  
c = 1500
m = 331
n = 500
```

Alguém sabe o motivo disso? E como eu posso descobrir qual superpixel cada pixel de uma imagem pertence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o motivo, hehe! A imagem é colorida, logo a matriz guarda a informação pra R, G e B juntos.